# Can scraping the transmission bad

Tags: toyota, automatic-transmission

I had to drive on a very poorly paved street a few weeks ago with my car, and it was so poorly paved that I felt I was offroading, due to the deep potholes, at one point, my car's underbody kinda hit the ground, and after that whenever I drive I feel that my transmission is kinda slow. Could there be effects from that hit that could affect my transmission? I drive a 95 corolla automatic.

Answer (score 1):

Look for any signs of the impact from underneath the vehicle. If the trans sump has been damaged then the chances are the trans internals may have also been damaged. For instance the oil pickup pipe may be partially displaced. Check also for damage to any linkages or hoses being misplaced on the outside of the trans. Have a look under the entire vehicle if possible. Damage could have been done to items like drive shafts being bent, brake cable or linkages being damaged and causing binding of the brakes. If you **do** feel that there is a differance following the incident on the rough roads and you are unable to give your vehicle a full under body inspection, then you should put your vehicle into your favourite repair shop for an inspection. You may have trouble brewing.

Comment: I misread your last sentence and was wondering why anybody would be trying to brew in their car...

Comment: It never surprises me what some people will do in their cars:-)